# show the selected multiple selected items in input using select2 on edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, jquery-select2

I want to get the selected values in the multiple select input field on edit.

I am using **select2** **version:4**

- I am having a **product** form which is having a field called "condition" which is using select2 multi select option.
- its working fine for now. i am adding these data to database as well.
- but when i want to edit the same product i waant to show the previously selected conditions items which are in database.

How can i achieve this in select2.

Please send me the link which helps me to do this.

Comment: just retrieve the data which were stored in the database and add it to select option. Or am I  missing something?

Comment: how can this be duplicate of the question link by @Pedram . Its totally different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (Select2 V.4)

```
 <select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>

<script>
  $('#example').select2({
      placeholder: 'Select a month'
  });

  $(function(){
    $("#example").select2().val(["FEB","JUN"]).trigger('change.select2');
  });
</script>
```